# If $∑_{n=1}^∞f_n $ converges uniformly on a set $A$, prove that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $A$

Tags: calculus

If $∑_{n=1}^∞f_n $  converges uniformly on a set $A$, prove that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $A$

I don't understand, if $∑_{n=1}^∞f_n $  converges uniformly on a set $A$, then $f_n ->0$ for sure, why do I have to prove it converges to zero again?

Comment: You know $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $0$. But uniformly? To prove this, you could use the fact that the series is Uniformly Cauchy. (See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83105/if-sum-f-k-converges-uniformly-in-x-then-f-k-to-0-uniformly-in-x).)

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91707/prove-if-sum-limits-n-1-inftyf-n-converges-uniformly-so-does-sum/91712#91712) for a proof that a uniformly convergent sequence is uniformly Cauchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s_n=f_1+\cdots+f_n$, and $s=\sum_{n=1}^\infty s$, and let $\varepsilon>0$.

The fact that  $s_n-s\to 0$, uniformly on $A$, implies that, there is an $N$, such that
$$
n\ge N\quad\Longrightarrow\quad |s_n(x)-s(x)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2},
$$
for all $x\in A$, and thus
$$
|f_{n+1}(x)|\le\big|\big(s_{n+1}(x)-s(x)\big)-\big(s_n(x)-s(x)\big)\big|\le
|s_n(x)-s(x)|+|s_{n+1}(x)-s(x)|<\varepsilon,
$$
for every $n\ge N$, and $x\in A$, or equivalently
$$
|f_n(x)|<\varepsilon,
$$
for every $n\ge N+1$, and $x\in A$.