# Uniform Convergence of Series Implies Uniform Convergence of the Related Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

**Question**:
Prove that if the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty u_n(x)$ converges uniformly on an interval, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n = 0$ uniformly on that interval.

**What I have so far:**
We are given:

$\forall \epsilon>0 \quad \forall x \in I \quad \exists N$ s.t. $\forall n \geq N \quad |(\sum_{k=1}^n u_k) - U| < \epsilon$
where $I$ is an interval and $U := \sum_{k=1}^\infty u_k$.

We also know that: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty u_k$ converges $\implies \lim_{n \to \infty} u_n = 0$
So $\forall \epsilon>0 \quad \exists N$ s.t. $\forall n \geq N \quad |u_n - 0| < \epsilon$.

Then
$|u_n| = |u_n + \sum_{k=1}^n u_k - \sum_{k=1}^n u_k|$
$= |(\sum_{k=1}^n u_k) - u_n - \sum_{k=1}^n u_k| \quad$ (factoring out $-1$)
$= |\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} u_k - \sum_{k=1}^n u_k|$
$\leq |\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} u_k| + |\sum_{k=1}^n u_k|$
$< \epsilon + \epsilon$
$= 2 \epsilon$

Is this useful in any way, or am I completely off? I know I have to prove that $u_n$'s convergence is uniform, but I'm not quite sure how.

Comment: Your last inequality does not hold. You can save yourself by adding and subtracting the limit, $L$, of the sum in the third line.  Alternatively:   you can use, or prove, that the sum is uniformly Cauchy. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91707/prove-if-sum-limits-n-1-inftyf-n-converges-uniformly-so-does-sum/91712#91712) for a proof. Then apply it as in [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83105/if-sum-f-k-converges-uniformly-in-x-then-f-k-to-0-uniformly-in-x).

Comment: @PeterSmith Okay. Why doesn't the inequality hold? And we haven't defined "uniformly Cauchy" in the course yet. Taking your advice and subtracting the limit of the sum, I get right back to $|u_n|$ again...

Comment: $|\sum_{k=1}^n u_k|$ need not be small. But $|U-\sum_{k=1}^n u_k|$ can be made small (I should have used $U$ before, not $L$). So write $$\Bigl|\,\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} u_k -\sum_{k=1}^n u_k\,\Bigr|  =\Bigl|\,\bigl(-U+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} u_k \bigr)-\bigl(-U+\sum_{k=1}^n u_k\bigr)\,\Bigr|$$ and apply the triangle inequality.

Comment: @DavidMitra Ah, of course. Okay. So applying the triangle inequality, we have

$|(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} u_k - U) - (\sum_{k=1}^{n} u_k - U)|$
$\leq |\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} u_k - U| + |\sum_{k=1}^{n} u_k - U|$
$< \epsilon + \epsilon = 2 \epsilon$
  
And so this implies u_n is convergent, but does it imply uniform convergence? Or do I have to manipulate the definition in the very first line in the initial post?

Comment: Yes to your first question. Fix $\epsilon>0$ and choose $N$ so that $|U(x)-\sum_{i=1}^n u_i(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$ and all $x$. Then your argument  shows (make the corrections) that  $|u_n(x)|<2\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$ and all $x$. So, $(u_n)$ converges uniformly to zero.

Comment: Note since the sum converges uniformly to $U$, the $N$ above in my last comment exists. Your statement after "we are given" is a bit off. (Given $\epsilon$, one $N$,  works for all $x\in I$.)